# How to check if a macro expands to something greater than a constant?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, conditionals

Suppose I have a loop:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \frm \in {1,...,6}{ \only<\frm>{
    % if \frm > 4: set \x to 1, 0 otherwise
    \node (foo) at (10+5*\x,7) {hello};
  }}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to "move" the node at a given slide, but I'm struggling to find a suitable way to express the conditional in the comment in TeX.

---

Edit: I tried `\ifthenelse` to no avail:

```
\node (foo) at (10+5*\ifthenelse{\frm<5}{0}{1},7) {hello};
```

Gives me this error, which I cannot parse at all

```
! Use of \beamer@only doesn't match its definition.
\new@ifnextchar ...served@d = #1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following hack should do the trick. I modified the coordinates a bit so they'd stay on the screen.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \frm in {1,...,6}{
    \draw (0,0) node {origin};
    \only<\frm>{
    % if \frm > 4: set \x to 1, 0 otherwise
    \ifnum\frm>4\relax\def\x{1}\else\def\x{0}\fi%
    \node (foo) at (5+5*\x,7) {hello};
  }}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why you are doing it and also I am guessing that this goes in a beamer presentation so the following seems to do what you might want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \frm in {1,...,6}{ 
    \onslide<\frm>{
    % if \frm > 4: set \x to 1, 0 otherwise
    \pgfmathparse{\frm > 4? 1 : 0}
    \node (foo) at (10 + 5*\pgfmathresult,7) {hello};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```